# Wiki: List of songs that are useful for learning Korean

Tags: resources

Please add **one song per answer**, including

- A link to the song
- A link to the lyrics
- Reasons why you think it is a good song to learn from

Comment: Meta post : http://meta.korean.stackexchange.com/questions/53/wiki-list-of-songs-that-are-useful-for-learning-korean

Comment: You Can Get Book Here For Free
[Click For Eps book 2019](https://www.amitpanta.com.np/2018/10/eps-question-2018-2019-For-Nepal-With-Answer-sheet.html)

Answer (score 3):

**[Epik High - Love Love Love](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1RTl3HXK_NI)**

[better quality sound, but not official video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D4R9nt1k4j4)

[lyrics](http://lyrics.wikia.com/wiki/%EC%97%90%ED%94%BD_%ED%95%98%EC%9D%B4_(Epik_High):Love_Love_Love)

Excellent for learning the '~을 해본 적' construction meaning 'I have experienced', or (in this song) 'have you ever experienced...'

Answer (score 3):

**[PSY - Gangnam Style (강남스타일)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9bZkp7q19f0)**

[lyrics](http://www.lyricsfreak.com/p/psy/gangnam+style_21031735.html)

Arguably, any ≥intermediate Korean learner should know and understand a song this famous! It's also good for practicing adjectives (형용사) and adjectival phrases.

Comment: But do not expect correct pronunciations from him. For example, he intentionally pronounces 이 as 에 (maybe more like /ɪ/) for 사나이.

Answer (score 3):

[**이소라 Lee Sora - 바람이 분다 Wind blows**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mRWxGCDBRNY)

[lyrics](http://music.naver.com/lyric/index.nhn?trackId=441889)

This song was selected as one of the seven songs with the most beautiful lyrics by 14 Korean poets in 2014.

[Related Huffington Post (Korea) article](http://www.huffingtonpost.kr/2014/10/09/story_n_5956990.html) titled "시인들이 뽑은 가장 아름다운 노래가사는 (The most beautiful lyrics chosen by poets)"

Other songs selected:

김광진의 '편지', 브로콜리너마저의 '보편적인 노래', 델리스파이스의 '고백', 김윤아의 '봄날은 간다', 루시드폴의 '물이 되는 꿈'

Answer (score 3):

[요조 Yozoh - 우리는 선처럼 가만히 누워 We lie quietly like a line](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8hiSYNFXXrk)

[Lyrics](http://music.naver.com/lyric/index.nhn?trackId=2316690)

This song was selected as one of the seven songs with the most beautiful lyrics by 14 Korean poets in 2014.

[Related Huffington Post (Korea) article](http://www.huffingtonpost.kr/2014/10/09/story_n_5956990.html) titled "시인들이 뽑은 가장 아름다운 노래가사는 (The most beautiful lyrics chosen by poets)"

Other songs selected:

김광진의 '편지', 브로콜리너마저의 '보편적인 노래', 델리스파이스의 '고백', 김윤아의 '봄날은 간다', 루시드폴의 '물이 되는 꿈'

Answer (score 3):

[**나얼 Naul - 바람기억 (Memory of the Wind)**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-T2XIVsucdQ)

[lyrics](http://music.naver.com/lyric/index.nhn?trackId=3314561)

Great song with slow tempo and useful Korean idiomatic expressions. The Youtube video has English + Hangul + Romanization subtitles.

Answer (score 2):

#### [EXO - Moonlight](https://www.youtube.com/watch?annotation_id=annotation_2721061281&feature=iv&src_vid=YsE66VgVQds&v=1v3rlpb4B8U)

The link is a video with lyrics, romanization and translation.

I think this song is good because it has a mix of sentence forms, including:

- informal intimate sentences the persona wishes to say to the other person (the one he loves?): verse two, later half of the bridge, and the recurring *그 날개가 젖으니*
- artistic descriptions of imagery: pre-chorus
- direct expression of personal experiences and feelings: verse one, chorus, first half of the bridge

Feedback please :-)

Answer (score 2):

[**마시따 벤드 (Masitta Band) - 돌멩이 (Stone)**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LCfweJA0PEE)

[lyrics](http://music.naver.com/lyric/index.nhn?trackId=3198031)

Our life is metaphorically expressed as '돌멩이 (stone)' and we can learn a lot of metaphorical and idiomatic expressions.

Answer (score 1):

[**버스커 버스커 (Busker Busker) - 벚꽃 엔딩**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tXV7dfvSefo)

[Lyrics](https://genius.com/Busker-busker-cherry-blossom-ending-lyrics)<sup>1</sup>

As *one of the most popular* songs among the South Korean public, this is good to catch some *important points on pronunciation*:

- 벚꽃 잎이 [벋꼰니피]
- 흩날리는 [흔날리는]
- 알 수 없는 [알ː쑤엄는]
- 네 as [니]<sup>2</sup> (*incorrect* but common in colloquial language)
- 겹쳐 as [겹처]
- 많아요 as [마ː나요]
- 많군요 as [만ː쿤뇨]<sup>3</sup> (*incorrect* but common in colloquial language)

By the way, you can ignore the symbol, ː, as most Koreans do.

---

<sup>1</sup> Reading English Translation *won't* really help you understand the lyrics because of some parts including 울려 퍼질 and 흩날리는. They are difficult to translate.

<sup>2</sup> [네] *only* is correct, but many songs will pronounce 네 as 니 and even have 니 in their lyrics because lots of Koreans cannot differentiate 네 (your) from 내 (my).

<sup>3</sup> [만ː쿠뇨] *only* is correct.

Answer (score 1):

[**여자친구(GFriend) - 시간을 달려서**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0VKcLPdY9lI)<sup>1</sup>

[Lyrics](https://genius.com/Gfriend-rough-lyrics)

Several usage points can be found:

- ...헤매이**고**<sup>2</sup> **있어** (present progressive)
- 좋아하**지만**, 해 봐**도**, 헤매여**도**<sup>3</sup>, and  **그렇지만** (contrast or concessive)
- ...하면 할수록 ("the more ... try to ...")
- ...만날 거야 (future or guess)
- 기다릴게 and 잡아 줄게 (promise or determination)
- 언제까지나 ("until whenever")
- ...될 수만 있다면 ("If only ... could be(come) ...")
- 어리긴 한가 봐 (emphasis on 어리다 and guess)
- 꿈처럼 and 기적처럼 (simile)
- 서툴기만 한대도<sup>4</sup> (emphasis on 서툴다 and concessive)

There are words for advanced learners:

- 끗
- 평행선

---

<sup>1</sup> Please be aware of some mistranslated lines especially in Chorus.

<sup>2</sup> 헤매이고 is incorrect; 헤매고 is correct.

<sup>3</sup> 헤매여도 is incorrect; 헤매도 is correct.

<sup>4</sup> 한대도 is incorrect; 하대도 is correct.