# Websites and internet resources for learning Korean

Tags: resources

I am a native Korean, and I am trying to help and communicate with other people here. I'm also learning other languages and have my own list of websites teaching them.

So I wonder which websites you people are using to learn Korean?

Please see [this meta question](https://korean.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53/questions-that-are-lists-of-resources) for guidelines on how to answer.

Comment: Hi dextto, welcome to the site. I didn't personally downvote this question, but on Stack Exchange, people are often wary of 'list questions'. Maybe you could read http://meta.korean.stackexchange.com/questions/53/wiki-list-of-songs-that-are-useful-for-learning-Korean and have a look at the linked songs question - would you like this question to be answered in a similar way?

Comment: In the meantime can I suggest that people answer this question with *one site per answer*, with a brief description of what's good about the site. The most useful sites can then be voted to the top.

Comment: @topo morto Sorry, I really didn't know that. I will try to ask in details next time. Thank you.

Comment: I want to recommend http://howtostudykorean.com, it used a different method of teaching.

Comment: No problem! I think we *can* manage some list questions (I asked http://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/331/wiki-list-of-songs-that-are-useful-for-learning-Korean, after all). It would just be good to be clear that it's a different type of question to the usual Stack Exchange question.

Comment: I see that you edited this to ask for the "Best website for learning Korean", but that's quite opinion-based. Would you mind if I edit your question a bit to be more like the 'songs' one?

Comment: No, go ahead. I'm learning how to use stackexchange. :)
Anyway, other people can edit my question's title?

Comment: @dextto yes, directly so if they have enough reputation. If they don't, they can still suggest edits, and their yet-to-be edits will be peer-reviewed by stack exchange users to check if they are good. If approved, their suggestions will be realized as actual edits.

Comment: Sorry to continue with the suggestions but I wonder if *not* accepting an answer for this question would be better? Having an accepted answer gives the impression that resource is the 'correct' one, and if another resource is upvoted more it will still appear below the accepted answer. Just a thought!

Comment: @topomorto I understand what you mean, but I think readers already know the accepted answer is just my opinion. I read other answers then picked the answer which I liked most. You don't have to worry too much.

Comment: I hope we will soon add http://korean.stackexchange.com/ to this list

Comment: I also like to talk in Korean very much. But since Korean is difficult, I would like to suggest an easy way to know.
[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vEEHQ.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vEEHQ.jpg)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I like Talk to me in Korean (TTMIK)

http://www.talktomeinkorean.com

Comment: I'm glad you like it!  They are real nice people and the content is also very good, isn't it? You can also find them in Podcast and Youtube.

Answer (score 6):

TTMIK is truly awesome, but you can find the list of some other useful online sources on Korean languages [here](http://www.topikguide.com/best-korean-language-resources-online/) too. I personally like lessons provided by **http://www.koreanclass101.com/** and **TTMIK**.

In these lessons, Korean language (and culture) are taught in an innovative,fun and unboring manner, and with the focus on teaching practical Korean (i.e. daily Korean). Grammatical rules are explained very well too. You can download many colorful lessons (PDF + audio) for free.

**PS**:

You can download some useful Textbooks (PDF, e-book, etc) on Korean language in:

- http://www.sejonghakdang.org/opencourse/textbook/textbook/list.do
- http://multiculture.dibrary.net/boards/show/801/50/4003/0/50.do
- http://search.4shared.com/q/CCAD/020/Korean%20learning%20PDF

If you like to buy some Korean language books, you can get them here too:

- http://www.darakwon.co.kr/koreanbooks/List.aspx?PAGE=2

Comment: Thanks, @Rathony. I know some websites for downloading books too. Shall I introduce them too?

Comment: As far as it is related with learning Korean, why not?

Comment: Koreanclass101 has the best pronunciation lessons (even native Koreans may learn something!) There are two series of lessons: [Ultimate Korean Pronunciation Guide](http://www.koreanclass101.com/index.php?cat=70) and [Pronunciation Series](http://www.koreanclass101.com/index.php?cat=37). (Free registration is required, but it is worth it)

Answer (score 3):

The Reddit Korean subgroup: [/r/Korean](https://www.reddit.com/r/Korean/)

- Where a lot of Korean language learners hold helpful discussions.
- Currently 15,888 members subscribed.
- According to the moderator, there are about 500 truly active members.
- A good place for questions/discussions that don't fit on this site.
- There's also a [chatroom](https://kiwiirc.com/client/irc.snoonet.org/?nick=#korean) there, but I haven't found that particularly useful.

Comment: I always wonder why would people ever find chatrooms useful..

Answer (score 2):

I've found the [Korean Wiki Project](http://www.koreanwikiproject.com/wiki/Main_Page) to be a useful resource. Mostly I just use free vocab memorization apps downloaded from Google Play (if that counts as an internet resource).

Comment: Thank you! I read some pages and I feel this is also very nice.

Answer (score 2):

[HowToStudyKorean.com](http://www.howtostudykorean.com/)

- Over 120 free online lessons that starts you from the very beginning.
- Eventually covers 9000 of the most common Korean words and
- 99.9% of the grammar used in Korean conversation.

I found this site after I could speak Korean pretty well. I bookmarked it anyways because it seemed I could still learn a lot from it.

My only complaint is the lessons seem a little long and verbose...

Answer (score 2):

[Learn to Read Korean in 15 Minutes](http://www.ryanestrada.com/learntoreadkoreanin15minutes/)

- Probably the quickest, easiest way to learn Hangul.
- Available for free.
- Here is a sample:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is a "semi-official" website for teaching the Korean language:
http://www.kosnet.go.kr/index.do?device=null

Semi-official, because it is produced by the National Institute for International Education, which is a government agency tasked with promoting Korea to people globally, although having said that it's not exactly a language institute like the Acadamie Francaise is to the French language (not sure if there is any such thing for the Korean language).

Comment: Hello Caesar, welcome to Korean Stack Exchange. The question is about "websites and internet resources for learning Korean" and the link doesn't seem to provide any help to learners.

Comment: Yep, an answer here would be more appropriate once that resource is up and running! For now, maybe you could drop a note in our chat instead? http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41465/korean-language.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I have changed my answer text to provide a direct response to the question. In the meantime, here is the original answer text:

Just dropping by to put in a plug for more contributors to help build the Duolingo Korean course: https://incubator.duolingo.com/courses/ko/en/status

I've found this site/app to be really effective at learning French from English, and I'm really desperate for the Korean course to be finished, so if anybody is in a position to help them complete the course, please help!

(I am not affiliated with Duolingo...)

Answer (score 1):

You should try out Parrot (http://meetparrot.com). It's for video chatting with Koreans. 7 minutes of only Korean, and then 7 minutes of only English. It's really useful for speaking as well as listening practice.

TTMIK is great too, but I think that's best for beginners who are just starting off. For advanced learners who want real conversation Parrot is the way to go! Plus you can exchange with real Koreans.
[image]

P.S. I'm the creator of the app, so please let me know if you have any suggestions :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are starting off as a complete beginner and are looking to learn some commonly used Korean words and phrases, I would suggest [Beginner Korean](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.shex.beginnerkorean).

If you are an intermediate or advanced learner, I would recommend [Topik Locker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.shex.topiklocker) app to practice or grow your Korean vocabulary.