# Best textbook to prepare for TOPIK 1?

Tags: topik

I've been studying Korean for the past few years and I want to finally take TOPIK I this year. I'm looking for the most helpful book I can buy to help me prepare. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: https://korean.stackexchange.com/search?q=books+on+korean

Comment: https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/537/websites-and-internet-resources-for-learning-korean/544

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the best sources to study for TOPIK?](https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/649/what-are-the-best-sources-to-study-for-topik)

Answer (score 0):

There are a large amount of books out there for learning Korean. I would suggest focusing on books that will specifically prepare you to do well on the TOPIK.

[This is one book I would suggest.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B019S7OJXY)

[This is another book that I would suggest.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07RPJKRR5)